# How to show ₹ symbol in GNUCash?

Tags: gnucash

In GUNCash INR currency symbol is showing by a question mark('?').

How to show ₹ symbol in this ?

USING Version: 2.6.18
Windows: 8.1 Pro

Comment: Off-topic. Check your character encoding (hopefully UTF-8) and your fonts (i.e. the font used to display currency in GNUcache)

Comment: I would like to ask a question about GNUCash. It is the software itself based not coding related. Which one is most proper ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the temporary solution for this.

Go to Tools --> Security Editor --> Currencies

Just put the symbol '₹ '   **along with a space**.

If you put only '₹' symbol, it will become '?' symbol after save.

May be it is an issue, and should be logged here...

https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash

Comment: Just started GnuCash. This solution was needed even in November 2018 in GnuCash version 3.3, Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Solution still valid in Jan 2020. Using GnuCash 3.7. Currencies will not appear unless you check the `Show National Currencies`, then you can edit the symbols as you want.

Comment: This solution is still valid for GnuCash 4.2 on Windows 10 Pro! Thanks!

Comment: It works in windows 11 and GNU Cash 4.12

Comment: This solution still works with GnuCash v.5.5+(2023-12-16) / Windows 10.